# How to extract big dataset from twitter streaming?

Tags: twitter-streaming-api

I was assigned a database project, data processing from Twitter stream and I need to use a dataset around 20gb.  So I downloaded twitter library from Python and wrote the following code:

```
# Import the necessary package to process data in JSON format
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json

   from twitter import Twitter,OAuth, TwitterHTTPError, TwitterStream


ACCESS_TOKEN = "<my_token>"
ACCESS_SECRET = "<my_secret>"
CONSUMER_KEY = "<my_key>"
CONSUMER_SECRET = "<my_secret>"

oauth = OAuth(ACCESS_TOKEN, ACCESS_SECRET, CONSUMER_KEY, 
CONSUMER_SECRET)


twitter_stream = TwitterStream(auth=oauth)


iterator = twitter_stream.statuses.sample().

for tweet in iterator:
    print json.dumps(tweet)
```

But after fetching abut only 725kb if data, the programme is terminating. What should  I do to fetch 20gb of data from twitter stream?